# problem in define variable on other class in Action Script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have 2 class  Class A , Class B.

I have a variable in Class a `DEGREE`.

```
package com.sample
{ 
    //CLASS A
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
    import flash.display.Stage; 
    import flash.events.Event; 
    import flash.display.Sprite; 
    import flash.sampler.StackFrame; 

    public class classA extends MovieClip
    { 
        public var DEGREE:Number = 0; 
        public function classA() 
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP , OnMouseUp);
        }

        function OnMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            DEGREE = this.flashshow.rotation;
        }
    }
}
```

when define class a in class b with under line :

class B :

```
public var myClassA:classA;

myClassA = new classA();
```

but when i get `DEGREE` in class b

```
trace(myClassA.DEGREE) ;
```

it equal ZER0 no 30.

```
package com.sample
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.display.Stage; 
    import flash.events.Event; 
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
    import com.MrMind.flashShow;

    public class classB extends MovieClip
    {
        public var mmm:classA = new classA(); 
        public function classB () : void
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , mee);
        }

        public function mee(evt:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            trace(mmm.DEGREE); // OUT PUT ZER0
        }
    }
}
```

anyone could help?

Comment: What is the full definition of DEGREE? And where is the assignment of 30 taking place?

Comment: var DEGREE:Number;  DEGREE = 30; DEGREE define in mouse_up event

Comment: And where the assignment is taking place? I am suspecting you are tracing the number before it is assigned. And is this public? If no, then how you are accessing in class B? Please post the real relevant code. Otherwise its difficult to guess where is the problem.

Comment: CLASS A  :  package com.sample    
{
     
//CLASS A

 
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.display.Stage;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.sampler.StackFrame;

 
 
 public class sample extends MovieClip 
 {
  
  
  public var DEG:Number = 0;
 
 
  
     
  
  public function sample() 
  {
   addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP , OnMouseUp);
   
  }
  
  
    
  function OnMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
  {
   
   DEG = this.flashshow.rotation;
      
   
  }
  
  
  
  
 }
 
}

Comment: CLASS B : package com.sample
{
 
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.display.Stage;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import com.MrMind.flashShow;

 public class classB extends MovieClip
 {
  
  public var mmm:sample = new sample();
    
  
  public function classB () : void
  {
   
   
   addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , mee);
   
   
   
  }
  
  public function mee(evt:MouseEvent):void
  {
   trace(mmm.DEG);   // OUT PUT ZER0
  }

Comment: can say example code for me .

Comment: Is DEG and DEGREE same? You have initialized it with zero. No wonder that trace output is zero.

Comment: If flashshow.rotation isnt changing the Degree won't either. Does it trace 30 if you were to trace flashshow.rotation in the mouseup event?

Answer (score 1):

you can use static variables if you want to access their values outside of a class without instantiating the class.  `public static var` is global, which some purists might lambaste you for using since they have the tendency of dilute the paradigm of object-oriented programming, so use them sparingly and with caution.

Document Class:

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.Sprite;

//Class
public class DocumentClass extends Sprite
    {
    //Constructor
    public function DocumentClass()
        {
        //Call ClassA's Static variable - Class A doesn't need to be instantiated.
        trace(ClassA.firstDegree);

        //Call CalssA's public variable - Error, class must first be instantiated.
        //trace(ClassA.secondDegree);
        //ERROR 1119: Access of possibly undefined property secondDegree through a reference with static type Class.

        //Issues may arrise via global values that can be set and retreived from anywhere.
        ClassA.firstDegree = 100;
        trace(ClassA.firstDegree);

        //Instantiate ClassA first, and then retreive its public variable
        var a:ClassA = new ClassA();
        trace(a.secondDegree);
        a.secondDegree = 50;
        trace(a.secondDegree);
        }
    }
}
```

Class A:

```
package
{
//Class
public class ClassA
    {
    //Static Variables
    public static var firstDegree:uint = 30;

    //Variables
    public var secondDegree:uint = 40;

    //Constructor
    public function ClassA()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
30
100
40
50
```

Comment: thx alot but i want change value and can't use static  ,  when i change a value of variable in mouseUp Event , dont set it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i see your variable is changed on mouseUp and your trace happen on Click. That might be the problem. You could try to change DEGREE value on mouseDown and trace it on mouseUp. It should return the changed value. I think the click event happen before the mouseUp event.

Best of luck,
marco